# Possible to change values in an array after it has been created?

Tags: arrays

For example [1,2,3] and i want to add 5 to the 2nd element so that I get [1,7,3]. Would this actually be possible?

Comment: this is typically possible simply by addressing the desired element through its index, as in A[1] = A[1] + 5 but again it might depend on the programming language of your choice.

Comment: yes. search for *manipulate array* + your required language.

Comment: Hey @javaman99 do mark the answer as correct by clicking the V type tick mark looking button next to the answer, it should turn green. This helps people on stack overflow with similar questions and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to alter the value of contents in the `array`. What is not possible is to change the size of the `array` after compilation. You can not alter the size of the `array` during run time.

The contents in your example can be altered using a code like this in C++ or Java:

```c++
int array[3] = {1,2,3};
// what you want in your example can be done just like this

array[1]=array[1]+5;

// contents of array[1], means 2 has been altered to 7 now

//you can also do the same with all the contents
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  array[i]=array[i]+5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be like this:

```
array[1] += 5;
```

Where `1` index the second value and `+=` increments itself by five. It must apply to most of the languages.